# I need that a button dissapears when I logout Facebook Android Studio

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, button

I have a problem when I logout using the Facebook API. Apart from the button to log in and out, I have another button that allows access to other activity, what happens is that when I logout I want to disappear the button that gives me access to the other activity and I can not do it, I have tried many combinations with all methods of the main activity and nothing works

Any suggestions?

Comment: Post your many combinations, so we can help you

Comment: use `setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a reference to the Facebook Login Button and set a click listener on it and when click is registered, logout using LoginManager instance and make all your logout procedure ( such as clearing stored access token, clearing cache, etc.) and then make visibility of the other button View.GONE

Eg:

```
LoginButton mBtnFbLogin = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
Button otherButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.other_button)
```

Now set click listener on it.

```
mBtnFbLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                // Make your logout procedure
                ...
                otherButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank your for your answer, the solution works. Finally I do this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null && com.facebook.Profile.getCurrentProfile() != null) {
    boton_volver.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    boton_volver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), EventosActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    } else {
        boton_volver.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take care when you make the button invisible. Click events works even if you make the view invisible